# How to add multiple progress divs to a div based on a List<T> object items

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am doing a Polling web application with ASP.NET Webforms and C#. Based on the number of answers stored in an object I want to display the same number of progress divs inside a div preset on the page in this format in C#.

```
<div class="pull-left">
 <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="AnswerOption" />
</div>
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="Val" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: Val">
        <b>Val</b> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried the approach below but all I saw was just one div instead of the same number of divs as the numbers of answers in the object. This is what I did:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lstValues.Count; i++)
{
    var answer = UtilityClass.Utility.SubstringElement(lstValues[i]);
    if (answer.Trim() == new PollAnswersService().GetByPollAnswerId(userResp.PollAnswerId).PollAnswerText)
    {
        ListItem valItem = new ListItem(lstValues[i], lstValues[i]);


        var divResults = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divResults"));
        divResults.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        string percentage = lstValues[i].Substring(lstValues[i].IndexOf("-") + 1);
        var percentVal = percentage.Remove(percentage.Length - 1).Trim();
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.Text = lstValues[i];
        rb.Checked = true;
        rb.Enabled = false;

        divResults.Controls.Add(rb);

        Panel pnlProgress = new Panel();
        pnlProgress.Attributes["class"] = "progress-bar progress-bar-info";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["role"] = "progressbar";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuenow"] = percentVal;
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuemin"] = "0";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuemax"] = "100";
        pnlProgress.Style["width"] = string.Format("{0}%;", percentVal);
        pnlProgress.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("{0}%;", percentVal)));


        divResults.Controls.Add(pnlProgress);
    }
    else
    {
        ListItem valItem = new ListItem(lstValues[i], lstValues[i]);
        ((RadioButtonList)e.Item.FindControl("rblPollResult")).Items.Add(valItem);


        var divResults = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divResults"));
        divResults.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

        string percentage = lstValues[i].Substring(lstValues[i].IndexOf("-") + 1);
        var percentVal = percentage.Remove(percentage.Length - 1).Trim();
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        rb.Text = lstValues[i];
        rb.Checked = true;
        rb.Enabled = false;

        //divResults.Controls.Add(rb);

        Panel pnlProgress = new Panel();
        pnlProgress.Attributes["class"] = "progress-bar progress-bar-info";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["role"] = "progressbar";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuenow"] = percentVal;
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuemin"] = "0";
        pnlProgress.Attributes["aria-valuemax"] = "100";
        pnlProgress.Style["width"] = string.Format("{0}%;", percentVal);
        pnlProgress.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(string.Format("{0}%;", percentVal)));


        divResults.Controls.Add(pnlProgress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am i correct in thinking that its the very last itemin the iteration that is added to the HTML at the end of the process?

Comment: @Derek I believe so. It is possible. But I don't know why since it is in a loop.

Comment: You need to debug your code, and check the number of child controls that divResults control has on thelast iteration of your loop. I would you as asp ListView control for something like this.

Comment: @Derek It shows only one control. That means as the loop goes on the child controls get replaced. Do you have a better method to do this as I believe you understand what I wanna achieve. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be pretty simple, declare this variable outside of the loop :-

```
var divResults = ((HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("divResults"));

for (int i = 0; i < lstValues.Count; i++){

// Your Code Here

}
```